# from a function, how do i get a return value in Lua

Tags: function, lua

How do I do below in Lua please?
I would like to get my variable returned to use it on another computation.

```
def xy(x, y):
  z = x * y
  return z

z = xy(2, 5)
z2 = z * 7
print (z2)
```

Comment: Just take a look (google) how a function can be written in Lua, there are so many tutorials available...

Comment: [SO Doc](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/lua/1250/functions/4078/defining-a-function#t=201704160040177978185)

Comment: couldn't find examples of any that returned a variable, but only used it as some printing of the result.  was trying to write it and wasn't successful, til now.:


function findC(a, b)
  c = (a*b)
  return c
end

c = findC(5, 2)
print (c)

Comment: @Newbie101 - Please make both `c` variables explicitly local by writing `local c = a*b` and `local c = findC(...)`.  In Python variables are automatically local, in Lua - automatically global.

Comment: As in most languages, a function can't return a variable, only a value; which is probably what you meant. In Lua, a function can return a list of zero or more values. The values are the results of expressions in the return statement. In this context, a variable is an expression.

Comment: This is Python code, not Lua code.

Answer (score 3):

```
local function xy(x, y)
    local z = x * y
    return z
end

local z = xy(2, 5)
local z2 = z * 7
print(z2)
```

Remove the first `local` if you want the function `xy` to be global.